# How to get the attribute '?attr/colorSecondary' in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, attr

Android Studio fails to install app if I add the following to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="?attr/colorSecondary" />
```

If I remove it, the app installs on devices / emulators well. What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
  android:resource="?attr/colorSecondary"
  tools:replace="android:resource"
/>
```

Also add this line in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
  "<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      package="com.yourpackagename"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">" <----  this line
```

Comment: Still getting the following error:

Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1455012049.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #85): <meta-data> requires an android:value or android:resource attribute'

Comment: Try adding `android:exported="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: android:exported="true" cannot work for meta-data entry or you can explain further what you mean